# The script django-admin is installed in '/tmp/somedir/deps/0/python/bin' which is not on PATH. Consider adding this directory to PATH

Tags: django, cloud-foundry

I am trying to host my Django application on Cloud Foundry, After installing the packages mentioned in requirement.txt file, I m getting error saying the package is installed in path "/tmp/somedir/deps/0/python/bin" which is not on Path. So I want to know how can I add this directory to the Path.

I am using CF CLI's CF push manifest.yml cmd to push the django application.

Adding the manifest file:

Manifest.yml:

```
applications:
- name: myapp
  domain: domain_name
  memory: 1024M
  disk_quota: 1024M  
  buildpack: python_buildpack
  command: bash ./run.sh 
  env:
    DISABLE_COLLECTSTATIC : 1
```

Adding run.sh file:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ -z “$VCAP_APP_PORT” ];
    then SERVER_PORT=XX;
    else SERVER_PORT=”$VCAP_APP_PORT”;
fi
echo port is $SERVER_PORT
echo [$0] Starting Django Server…
python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:$SERVER_PORT — noreload
```

Comment: can you post your yml

Comment: added the yml file

Comment: Where are you seeing this error? Is it when you `cf push`? If so, can you provide a full set of logs from running `cf push` and from `cf logs` as your app tries to start? Are you trying to `cf ssh` and run this command and seeing the error? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think this is simply a bug in the Python Buildpack, that will be solved when https://github.com/cloudfoundry/python-buildpack/pull/601 is merged.